# QGIS error message "raster layer data provider is invalid"

Tags: wms, qgis-3

When I try to add a new WMS Layer from an URL into QGIS, it seems I can add the layer but when I try to open it I get the following error message: "invalid layer: raster layer data provider is invalid".

Any idea where the problem is? Is it the URL (which should be correct) or something with my QGIS. I'm using the QGIS 3.4.6 Version.

the WMS URL used was: "https://www.wms.nrw.de/gd/bk050?"

I have not used an other Provider because it is the only one I know for these data

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to give an answer with these details. Could you share the WMS URL? Have you tested with some other WMS server that is known to be good?

Comment: hi, thanks for the Reply. The WMS URL is: https://www.wms.nrw.de/gd/bk050?VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: please edit the question with the requested information

Comment: Works for me with QGIS 3.4.4.

Comment: I tried several layers and they all worked for me in QGIS 3.6.1. That service has many layers; please specify which ones aren't working for you. Are any of them working?

Comment: Actually, I just realized they all do work for me. I get the error message and at first nothing appears on my screen, but when I zoom in close enough the layers suddenly appear. I don't know why I need to zoom in first, but as long as the layers work I'm happy.

Comment: In order to avoid a too big data load for the server, some detailled WMS only become visible at large scales. E.g. cadastral data (ALKIS) for Brandenburg is only visible at 1:5000 or larger.